# Removing slash in Jmeter and passing the value to next api

Tags: jmeter

From csv confi i am passing a variable for encryption Api
that is `"analytical_url":"api\/apply_weekoff"`

i need to replace `\/` with empty from "api/apply_weekoff" on passing to encryption api

any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If you have this value stored in a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) you can use [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) like:

```
${__groovy(vars.get('foo').replace('\\\\'\, ''),)}
```

[image]

The above code line assumes that you have `foo` JMeter Variable with the value of `"analytical_url":"api\/apply_weekoff"`

Alternatively you can use [__strReplace() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#strReplacesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-4-0-font-sup) like:

```
${__strReplace(${foo},\\\\,,)}
```

[image]

`__strReplace()` function is not present in default JMeter distribution bundle you will need to install it additionally using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Comment: Thank You So much its working with __strReplace() function. But for example i am passing five data through csv config  is there any possibility to use this __strReplace() function. Currently i have used Tools->Function Helper to convert and passed it in the path.